# what is a good technique to output a solution using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

This question is specifically addressed towards the coin change problem.
I know the algorithm to find the optimal number of coins used to find change for any amount, and I also understand it but what I don't understand is how could I "mark" if you will the path taken to find such solution.  I have tried to use parent pointers, which I'm sure is the way to do it, but I simply don't know how I would implement it.  Here's an example.
Example:
given coin denominations: 1, 10, 25
Change: 30
Optimum solution requires: 3 coins
Coins used:  10, 10, 10

I am not really that good at solving dynamic programming problems.

Comment: Assume you know optimal solution for 1 through 29. How could you use it to find solution for 30?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to let you guys know that my current solution to the problem is only kept in an array, I'm not making the table.  So I have the solution from 1 -29 but of number of coins used, not which coins.  I'm sorry if this should be intuitive but it really isn't to me.  I guess my question is:  If I were to implement a 2d table with amounts from 0 to n as rows and coin denominations from 1 to k as columns, what would be the values of each cell and how would I calculate them?

Comment: You can solve it more efficiently. Keep a pointer to the previous optimal solution from which the current optimal solution is derived. Eg. For 10 have a link to zero. For 20 link to 10, and, for 30 link to 20. Now all you have to do is backtrack. 30's link is 20, so that is 30-20 = 10, 20's link is 10-> 20-10 = 10 and 10-0=10. That is how you get 3 10s

Answer (score 2):

You know that T[30] = 3. You must find a T[30-c] = 2, trying all c in {1, 10, 25}. As T[30-10] = 2, you know you'll use a 10 cents coin and now must solve the problem for T[20].

Repeat this until T[0] = 0.